# Unable to import PyPDF2 module in Python 3.6.0 Shell

Tags: python, pypdf

I am receiving following error within `Python 3.6.0` IDLE Shell

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

This occurs even after I have run the command `python -m pip install --user pyPDF2` within the Command Prompt successfully.

I have tried running `import sys` followed by `print(sys.path)` which returns several file paths, however, none of them appear to be `PyPDF2`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use pip3 since your using python 3.6 I just did the following on my system: 
`pip3 install pypdf2`

and then tested that it worked with the following import statement:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
```